# Display a message while executing a method

Tags: methods, thread-safety

In my app, I read/parse data that takes some time. While that process is going on I want to display a message on screen indicating the process going on. I beileve I got to use Thread for it, but don't get an idea how to use and implement it.The calling method may throw exception or so.

Any idea/tip on how to achieve the task. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you enlighten us on what language this is? C#, VB.NET, Java, C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you're using .Net.

You should use the [BackgroundWorker component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Perform your operation in its `DoWork` event (which runs on a background thread), call `ReportProgress` to post messages for the UI, and handle `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` to update the UI.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, Can you give me an idea on how to implement it. I have Login & MainUI forms. In Login, on clicking a button, certain operations are done (which takes time) and then on successful completion, MainUI is shown where again while displaying certain things are done. In MainUI also on clicking something certian activities are done. I had a look but couldn't get on how to start with it as it will be used in 2-3 classes so far. Would be better if you can help me get a starting point regarding my requirements.  -Thanks

Comment: Do the operations in `DoWork`, and show the form in `RunWorkerCompleted`.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, that helped me gain my goal. Thanks a lot.